# Better sub navigation for a project management app

Tags: mockup

Below is a rough mock up of my current layout. Some how the inner navigation of

- Issues
- Wiki
- Team
- Settings

dont really stand out, also it does not give a feel that the current page is a result of selection of that navigation.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGf1ZV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Any suggestions to improve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the table to look like a result of the navigation buttons, you could move them down and make them look like tabs.

And to make them stand out, you could slightly increase their size and use colors that stand out. Although I think it stands out sufficiently for a wireframe.

You could also consider adding icons to the navigation buttons, because the brain processes visual aids faster than text.